# Symfony2 Permission Denied error while creating a bundle

Tags: symfony

First of all, I want to say I might be missing something basic, but I'm actually new in Symfony.

While I'm creating a bundle from terminal(I'm using mac), it gives me that error;

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  The stream or file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/logs/dev.log" cou  
  ld not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Here is the code for creating a bundle

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Ens/JobeetBundle --format=yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your permissions were not set correctly. Here is how to set it up - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: About half way down the page is a Checking Symfony Application Configuration and Setup section. Go through all of the setting up permissions and one should fix the issue